# open pdf file from assets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-viewer

I am trying to open PDF file using flutter_fullpdfview 1.0.12, i have the PDF file located under assets folder but somehow i am getting error unable to find file. I tried several options but none of them worked all return same error. Below are the functions i tried to load file and both of them failed with same error.

```
  Future<File> copyAsset() async {
      Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      String tempPath = tempDir.path;
      File tempFile = File('$tempPath/copy.pdf');
      ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load('assets/jainaarti.pdf');
      await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bd.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
      return tempFile;
    }

Future<File> fromAsset(String asset, String filename) async {
// To open from assets, you can copy them to the app storage folder, and the access them "locally"
    Completer<File> completer = Completer();
    try {
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      File file = File("${dir.path}/$filename");
      var data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
      var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
      await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
      completer.complete(file);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error parsing asset file!');
    }
    return completer.future;
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the pdf library you are using is set up to use a system filepath to load the pdf. Unfortunately, this differs from the asset path that you have access to, and Flutter currently does not support the ability to get an assets system filepath at runtime. The only way I can find to use that library is to transfer the files to a known directory, and load from there. Rather than do this, I would recommend the [native_pdf_view](https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_view) library, as it supports asset loading as well as full screen. You should be able to implement it as follows:

```
final pdfController = PdfController(
  document: PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/copy.pdf'),
);

return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: PdfView(
      controller: pdfController,
    )
  ),
);
```

-- EDIT --

To switch pages, if you want to start the viewer on a different page, just edit the initialPage in the pdfController

```
final pdfController = PdfController(
    document: PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/copy.pdf'),
    initialPage: 2
  );
```

If you want to switch pages after the pdfView has been created, you can call jumpToPage() or animateToPage() from anywhere, provided you can get a reference to the pdfController, and that it and the pdfView have been instantiated.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: PdfView(
              controller: pdfController,
            )
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Page 2"),
            onPressed: (){
              pdfController.jumpToPage(2);
              //  -- or --
              pdfController.animateToPage(2, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.linear);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I did try this option but even with that i get error File Not found. You can see screenshot from assets the file does exist and assets folder specified in pubspec.

Comment: Can you try removing the - assets/ listing and replacing it with - copy.pdf?
Also, are you running `flutter pub get`?

Comment: I tried just file name, even that didn't work. No i am not running flutter pub get..

Comment: Tried running flutter pub get.. no change.

Comment: Just updated the answer, hopefully this can fix the issue. Also, after editing the pubspec.yaml file, you should run flutter pub get in the application root directory, as this will fetch any dependencies you have added or changed.

Comment: Alex i did try running flutter pub get, but still application unable to find the files.

Comment: I updated my answer to address this. That library relies on having a system filepath to the pdf, but flutter currently does not have a method for you to get the system filepath for an asset. I recommend using a different library like the one I showed in the example above.

Comment: Cool.. that worked. Not sure why other libraries didn't work. Do you know how to open exact page in this? i see jumptoPage method but not sure where to place, i tried before onDcoumentLoaded and inside it but it didn't move to page i want.

Comment: @Akshay, I added to my answer to show how to switch pages, hope this helps!