# Flutter web doesn't recognise pdf file format

Tags: flutter, assets, flutter-web

I'm trying to show the pdf file when pushing the button but no success so far. Can there be the reason that the format of the pdf file has that question mark on the icon meaning the framework doesn't recognise the format?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, the Assets folder can contain any file regardless of the file extension. Have you define your assets folder in pubspec.yaml like this?

```
  assets:
  - assets/pdf/
```

If yes you can use [native_pdf_view](https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_view) library as it supports asset loading as well as full screen. You should be able to implement it as follows:

```
final pdfController = PdfController(
  document: PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/copy.pdf'),
);

return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: PdfView(
      controller: pdfController,
    )
  ),
);
```

Original link to the post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295588/open-pdf-file-from-assets-flutter).